# Public to private subnet traffic control on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, subnet, private-network-access

I'm reading up on AWS [VPCs and subnets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html) and I have a few related scenarios I'm unsure about.

Say my app backend consists of:

- a few load-balanced EC2 instances running a public facing REST API (web service); browsers and REST clients will be making requests against this API and so I assume it would go in a public subnet; we'll call this the `public-service`
- an RDS MySQL DB
- several non-public-facing REST APIs that will be used exclusively by the `public-service`; we'll call these the `private-services`; I assume these would go in a private subnet since nothing from the outside world is communicating directly to them

It *sounds* like I need to create a public subnet that contains:

- the load balanced EC2 instances for the `public-service` and all the respective "stuff" that goes along with that (balancer listeners, balancer target groups, security groups, etc.); and
- a NAT gateway so that when the `public-service` makes a call to a `private-service`, the response coming back from it can maintain a connection to the `public-service`

Is my understanding here correct? Either way, what types of AWS resources are needed to allow `public-service` in a public subnet to talk to `private-services` in a private subnet? I've heard of "network ACLs" and wonder if they come into play here at all, or would it be accomplished via routes on a routing table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the load balanced EC2 instances for the public-service and all the
> respective "stuff" that goes along with that (balancer listeners,
> balancer target groups, security groups, etc.);

Not really. Only the load balancer absolutely needs to be in the public subnet. Traffic between public and private subnets within the same VPC is entirely open by default. It's traffic between your VPC and the Internet that you need to be thinking about here, and that only happens at your load balancer.

> a NAT gateway so that when the public-service makes a call to a
> private-service, the response coming back from it can maintain a
> connection to the public-service

No, that is not at all what a NAT gateway is used for. A NAT Gateway is not used at all for communication between public and private subnets. A NAT Gateway is only needed to allow things in private subnets to access the Internet. For example if your EC2 instance in a private subnet needed to download a file from the Internet, then that subnet would need a route to a NAT Gateway in order for that to work.

Comment: Thanks @Mark B (+1). Is it fair to say you might advocate a scenario where the public subnet contains an ALB (balancer) and the individual EC2 nodes are living inside a private subnet? If so, any special routing/rules/gateways necessary to allow for that setup (`REST clients <--> ALB in public <--> EC2 in private <--> other EC2 in private`)?

Comment: There are zero special "routing/rules/gateways" necessary for that scenario. The default VPC settings will work fine in that scenario. The only thing would be the need for a NAT Gateway in the public subnet(s), and a route to the NAT Gateway in the route table of the private subnets, if those EC2 servers needed to reach out directly to the Internet for some reason (like to install software updates).